# Add a gesture recogniser to a PDFView

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uigesturerecognizer, touchesbegan

I'm trying to add a gesture recogniser to a PDFView using PDFKit. I am using the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, PDFDocumentDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView?

/// - Tag: SetDelegate
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "pdf") {
        if let document = PDFDocument(url: documentURL) {

            // Center document on gray background
            pdfView?.autoScales = true
            pdfView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            // 1. Set delegate
            document.delegate = self
            pdfView?.document = document
        }
    }
   func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let currentPoint = touch.location(in: pdfView)
            print(currentPoint)
        }
    }

    func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let currentPoint = touch.location(in: pdfView)
            print(currentPoint)
        }
    }

    func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let currentPoint = touch.location(in: pdfView)
            print(currentPoint)
        }
    }


}

// 2. Return your custom PDFPage class
/// - Tag: ClassForPage
func classForPage() -> AnyClass {
    return WatermarkPage.self
  }

}
```

The PDFView has a document attached to it (PDFDocument() which in turn has opens a PDFPage. When the code compiles the touches are not recognised. What is the best way to recognise touches on a PDFPage?

Comment: If you want the PDFView to respond to touches, you need to subclass PDFView. It looks like the user is touching the PDFView, but you are expecting touches on the main view of the view controller. It is also easier to use actual gesture recognizers than dealing with touches.

Comment: Thanks Henrik. I added a UITapGestureRecognizer to the ViewController and I can then print out "tap" to the console. I can't seem to determine the location of that tap on the pdf. I'm trying to simply work out how to annotate a pdf using the features of Apple's PDFKit but it proving to be a little more tricky for me than I expected.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you are trying to do. If you want to draw on the PDF, you need to deal with the touches. You can put an image view on top of your PDFView, and draw into a context on that image view. You can then add that image as an annotation to the PDF. If you want to detect swipes and taps, you should use a gesture recognizer.